# Why am i getting this error nodejs install on centos

Tags: node.js, installation, centos, yum

I have Centos 7.9 server and I'm trying to install nodejs.

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo bash -
```

repository is configured in the file /etc/yum.repos.d/nodesource-el7.repo

after that when typed sudo yum install nodejs its returned:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nodejs.x86_64 2:18.13.0-1nodesource will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit) for package: 2:nodejs-18.13.0-1nodesource.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) for package: 2:nodejs-18.13.0-1nodesource.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.13.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.13.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
mod_fcgid-2.3.9-6.el7.x86_64 has missing requires of httpd-mmn = ('0', '20120211x8664', None)
```

and I can't install any other version of nodejs